# Apply linear impuls to pushed point - Box2D on Android

Tags: android, iphone, box2d, jbox2d

I would like to get a shape to move from middle bottom to the point I'm touching. Issue is to solve the angle (or degree?) to the touched point.

```
float angle = ?
float power = calculatePower(touchY);
Vec2 impulse = new Vec2(angle, power);
Vec2 point = body.getWorldCenter(); // to prevent rotation of shape
body.applyLinearImpulse(impulse, point);
```

Anyone got a suggestion?

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Thanks to Andrews answer. Here is the working code:

```
Point delta = new Point(touchX - bodyX, touchY - bodyY);
double angle = Math.atan2(delta.y, delta.x);
Vec2 direction = new Vec2((float)Math.cos(angle), (float)-Math.sin(angle));
float power = calculatePower(touchY);
Vec2 impulse = new Vec2(power * direction.x, power * direction.y);
Vec2 point = body.getWorldCenter();
body.applyLinearImpulse(impulse, point);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code looks like this. `atan2` is standard math function

```
Vec2 delta  = touchPoint - body.position;
float angle = math.atan2(delta.y, delta.x);
```

This line `Vec2 impulse = new Vec2(angle, power);` looks very strange though. You are using `angle` as `x` value and `power` as `y`. That does not make much sense. I think your goal is to apply impulse of power `power` in direction of `angle`. In that case the code should look like this:

```
Vec2 dir     = Vec2(math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle));
Vec2 impulse = power * dir;
```

But since `delta` and `dir` only differ in their magnitude you can simplify calculating the impulse as:

```
Vec2 delta   = touchPoint - body.position;
Vec2 dir     = delta.normalize();
Vec2 impulse = power * dir
```

Comment: Im struggeling with `Vec2 impulse = power * dir`. Vec2 is not a float. How to do this `Vec2 impulse = new Vec2(?,?)` ?

Comment: @arcone: vector support scalar multiplication. I'm not 100% sure if it is supported in jbox2d though. As a workaround you can do: `Vec2 impulse = new Vec2(power * dir.x, power * dir.y)`